# If $H$ is permutable and $A$ is a subgroup of $H$, is $A$ then permutable?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, $A\le H$ where $H$ is a proper subgroup of $ G$.

How to show that  if $H$  is permutable in $G$ (i.e. $HB = BH$ for all $B\le G$) then $A$ is permutable in $G$?

Well, I started by assuming the opposite (if $A$ is not permutable then $H$ is not permutable) and got two cases, when $B$ is $H$ and not, but I couldn't continue. Can you give me a hint, please?

Comment: Well, $AH=H=HA$.

Comment: Anyway, it's not true in this form: consider $H=G$..

Comment: I've fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: But I still don't get it... How I can use that when B is not H ?

Comment: It's not true though.

Comment: Still? Can you give me a hint for a counter example please? @the_fox

Comment: Find an example of a group $H$ with a subgroup $A$ that is not permutable, then let $G$ be the direct product of $H$ with another group.

Comment: $G=D_8$, $H$ a maximal subgroup of $G$ and $A$ a subgroup of order $2$ of $H$ which is not normal in $G$. The point is not so much to actually find a counterexample, which may be tedious, but to suspect that a counterexample exists. If what you asserted were true, then it would imply something "too strong": that every subnormal subgroup of a group is permutable.

Comment: @the_fox Oh my god! Now I got it!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you so much!

Comment: Here's how you can thank me properly: answer your own question by showing that $D_8$ is the smallest counterexample to your assertion. As a bonus, implement Derek's suggestion.